# powershell: how to evaluate a string

Tags: powershell, eval

My file `a.txt` contains:

`delete from test_$suffix`

My PowerShell is:

```
$a = get-content a.txt
$suffix = "tableA"
```

How would I manipulate `$a` to obtain the string `delete from test_tableA` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$a=get-content a.txt
$suffix="tableA"

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($a)
```

Comment: Just be aware that if $a contains a quoted string (e.g. $a = 'delete from "test_$suffix"') you're going to lose your quotes when it gets expanded.

Comment: That is true. Same goes for $ signs. You can escape them with a tick `. Also, the here string technique only allows lines of recognizable PowerShell. I cannot have 'This is text' in the file (without the quotes). Enabling that is useful when doing templating type applications.

Comment: I don't understand this part: "Also, the here string technique only allows lines of recognizable PowerShell. I cannot have 'This is text' in the file (without the quotes). Enabling that is useful when doing templating type applications."
http://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/here-string-test/

Comment: My apologies, the testfile.txt I tested against was saved from ISE as Unicode, I re-saved it as Ascii and it worked.

Comment: No problem.  I've had times when I've thought I understood things better than I did, and made statements were just flat wrong.  I hate when I do that, and wanted to be sure this wasn't one of those times.

Comment: Awesome. This was a perfect fix for what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.4#executioncontext-expandstring

Answer (score 36):

[`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) is the equivalent.

```bash
$strExpression = "5 + 5 -eq 10"
Invoke-Expression $strExpression
True
```

See [this blog post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176880.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that, accepted answer did not worked for me, it just echoed variable contents. Your answer works well and even shorter

Comment: The accepted answer answers the OP's question of doing a "format string".  This answers the title of the question of how to eval a string.  If you just want to do "format string", the accepted answer is safer as it will not run arbitrary code (in case the input file is malicious)

Comment: @AmbroseLeung, good contrast, but note that `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` is _not_ inherently safer, because arbitrary commands can be embedded in an expandable string via `$(...)`; e.g., `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('$(Get-Date)')`

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for that - you are correct.  I thought that if you read $(...) from a file, powershell would escape the $, but this is not the case.  Perhaps sanitizing user input (replace $ with ``$)  `...ExpandString((gc myinput.txt).Replace('$','\`$'))` - there's probably some way to bypass this as well?  Best to avoid expanding user input

Comment: @AmbroseLeung: Given that expanding _variable_ references in the string (e.g, `$suffix`) is the very point of using `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` in the case at hand, the challenge is to selectively ignore embedded `$(...)` _subexpressions_. Doing this robustly, without getting tricked by escaping embedded in the source is somewhat tricky: `$a = $a -replace '(?<!\`)((?:\`\`)*)\$\(', '$1\`$$('`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way. Variables in a double-quoted here-string get substituted automatically.  Just be sure your input file conforms to the PS rules for here-strings.

```
 function convertto-herestring { 
 begin {$temp_h_string = '@"' + "`n"} 
 process {$temp_h_string += $_ + "`n"} 
 end { 
     $temp_h_string += '"@' 
     iex $temp_h_string 
     } 
 } 

 $suffix = "tableA"

 get-content testfile.txt

 delete from test_$suffix

 get-content testfile.txt | convertto-herestring

 delete from test_tableA
```