# Expand string Variable stored via Single Quote in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variable-expansion, remote-execution

I have a scenario where I need to construct a powershell path as `$RemotePath = '$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\Shell.lnk'`. This variable gets passed to a remote machine where it needs to be executed. The remote machine receives this as a string variable. How do I expand the string to evaluate `$env:USERPROFILE`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Expand the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836913/1630171) on the remote side:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($RemotePath)
```

Comment: Be aware that like `Invoke-Expression` and `[ScriptBlock]::Create()`, `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString` could be exploit using malicious code injections, see: [Rule for the use of the command: [ScriptBlock]::Create](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1454)

Answer (score 1):

By using a double quotes. PowerShell won't expand variables inside single-quoted strings.

Comment: When using double quotes the variable is expanded on the local side, not on the remote side as the OP wants.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the correct answer, and the explanation :)

Comment: Yup. As Ansgar mentioned, my requirement is to evaluate the expression on the remote machine, since I want the UserProfile value from the remote machine.