# Powershell string substitute masked variable

Tags: powershell

I want to substitute a variable to existing string, say:

```
$x = "Hello `$xxx friend"
$xxx = 777
similar_to_js_exec($x) # i need here "Hello 777 friend"
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: depending on your situation, you may find alternate concepts worth while. take a look at the `-f` string format operator and the `here-string` construct. the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet is considered highly risky [similar to sql injection] AND is so often used in malware that it is often entirely blocked.

Comment: I've used $url = Invoke-Expression ("""" + $_["ConnectionUri"].Value + """"), ugly :)
Actually there no user input, only hardcoded, so no injection.This is an Exchange endpoint depending of Azure envrionment, CN, DE, GOV, so had to pass an URL with parameter which has another parameter ie."https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveId?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=$UseTokenAuth". But thank you for the help !

Comment: ah! thank you for the added info. [*grin*] ///// please, take a look at the `-f` operator. it _usually_ makes that nasty nested set of quotes entirely unneeded.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey nice feature, this is the same as .NET String.Format(), of course i can use it, but already have used the code above, and it faster than just String.Format(), but thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand string Variable stored via Single Quote in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226606/expand-string-variable-stored-via-single-quote-in-powershell): `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($x)`

Comment: @iRon Yes, it's worked (with $UseTokenAuth locally defined) - PS:  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("https://outlook.office365.cn/PowerShell-LiveId?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=`$UseTokenAuth"), make it as answer

Comment: @OlegSkripnyak - i see that you got your actual problem solved ... good to know! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Invoke-Expression`

```
$x = '"Hello $xxx friend"'
$xxx = 777
Invoke-Expression $x
```

Comment: I am running it locally and it works, what error are you getting?

Comment: @OlegSkripnyak make sure you are using the quotes as I use them. Invoke-Expression will take whatever is in the string and execute it, so you need first single quotes `'` and then double quotes `"`

Comment: Your variant is good working, just have to embed my var into single quotes, thank you

Comment: Had to change it to some wonderful construction, where $_ is .NET Dictionary<string,string> PS:
$url = Invoke-Expression ("""" + $_["ConnectionUri"].Value + """")