# I need to resolve a variable name coming in from a database

Tags: variables, powershell

I have a situation where the database I am using contains an actual Variable name from my script in the text of the field. I want to pull that text into the session, resolve that variable name and use it.
Example:
Database field contains the Subject of an email:
The file named $AFPFilename is ready for your review!

When I pull this into my Powershell session the $AFPFilename string is not resolved as the actual value of $AFPFilename variable that was set earlier in the session. 
Example:
$AFPFilename = "AFP_File_Date_.afp"
(from database)$Subject = "The file named $AFPFilename is ready for your review!"

I want it to read:
The file named AFP_File_Date_.afp is ready for your review!

I have tried dozens of ways to get it to work and I am finally at a dead end. Any suggestions would be great appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide some [sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can figure out what you're doing. You should also tell us what those other attempts were, so we don't just end up telling you to try them again.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString().

An answer to a similar question nicely demonstrates its use:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836913/4040187